# Finding IQR of groups of rows

Tags: r, iqr

I am wanting to find the IQR of a range of values in a dataframe. These values are also grouped, therefore I need to find the IQR of each group in the dataframe. I have the following table:

```
 Block DNAname  Spot_Size   Molarity    Cy3_Fluorescence
 1  DNA 01  100pl   100 14266
 1  DNA 01  100pl   100 16020
 1  DNA 01  100pl   100 15705
 1  DNA 01  100pl   100 15783
 1  DNA 01  100pl   100 15834
 1  DNA 01  100pl   50  12248
 1  DNA 01  100pl   50  12209
 1  DNA 01  100pl   50  12511
 1  DNA 01  100pl   50  12316
 1  DNA 01  100pl   50  12469
 1  DNA 01  100pl   25  9626
 1  DNA 01  100pl   25  9804
 1  DNA 01  100pl   25  9794
 1  DNA 01  100pl   25  10020
 1  DNA 01  100pl   25  9739
 1  DNA 01  100pl   10  7158
 1  DNA 01  100pl   10  6802
 1  DNA 01  100pl   10  7378
 1   DNA 01 100pl   10  5949
 1  DNA 01  100pl   10  7484
 1  DNA 01  100pl   5   5257
 1  DNA 01  100pl   5   5560
 1  DNA 01  100pl   5   6076
 1  DNA 01  100pl   5   5925
```

I run the following code to find the IQR:

```
aggregate(Cy3.DNA1.100pl.1uM$Cy3_Fluorescence, list(Molarity=
    Cy3.DNA1.100pl.1uM$Molarity, Spot_Size=Cy3.DNA1.100pl.1uM$Spot_Size ), IQR)
```

This gives me the ouput:

```
   Molarity  Spot_Size   x
      5     100pl    384
     10     100pl    576
     25     100pl     65
     50     100pl    221
    100     100pl    129
```

This output groups all the molarities correctly but the IQR is not correct. If the code above has mean as a function instead of IQR the value for x (the function value) is correct as so:

```
   Molarity Spot_Size       x
    5     100pl       5752.4
   10     100pl       6954.2
   25     100pl       9796.6
   50     100pl      12350.6
  100     100pl      15521.6
```

The expected IQRS should be as follows:

```
Molarity IQR
100      324.25
50       258
25       363
10       519.5
5        400
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If any one has any ideas how I could perform this function for IQR, when there are groups of spot sizes (where spot size ranges from 100pl-400pl) including the molarity categories I would like to hear them.

Thank you kindly SO.

Comment: the `IQR` uses `quantile` function, which in turn uses `9` algorithms with `type` argument. By default, it uses `type=7`.  For example, you can change the `type` `aggregate(Cy3.DNA1.100pl.1uM$Cy3_Fluorescence, list(Molarity=
     Cy3.DNA1.100pl.1uM$Molarity, Spot_Size=Cy3.DNA1.100pl.1uM$Spot_Size ), IQR, type=5)`   From the help page of `?IQR`  `IQR(x, na.rm = FALSE, type = 7)`

Comment: Hi Akrun, thank you for your comment. I have tried the various types however they do not return the true IQR. I think it may be a problem with the fact that I want to find the IQR for the groups of  5,10,25,50 and 100 with major group of spot size. I think the IQR is being calculated taking the groups as numerical values rather than categories. Although I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: It may be better to post the expected IQR as well for the example data.

Comment: No problem, see the revised question

Comment: No idea how you calculated it.  According to `?IQR` `Note that this function computes the quartiles using the
     ‘quantile’ function rather than following Tukey's recommendations,
     i.e., ‘IQR(x) = quantile(x, 3/4) - quantile(x, 1/4)’`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear if your problem is about aggregating, or about your (??) definition of IQR. There are many ways to calculate IQR (see [this](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/CS144/Introduction_to_Computer_Networking/wiki/HRP258/example-r-classwork-solutions-using-r/calculating-inner-quartile-range-r/) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile)). As far as I can tell, none of them yield the results in your post.

As far as aggregating based on spot size and molarity, here are two ways:

```
# use aggregate(...) in base R - will be slow with large datasets
aggregate(Cy3_Fluorescence~Molarity+Spot_Size,df,IQR)
#   Molarity Spot_Size Cy3_Fluorescence
# 1        5     100pl            478.5
# 2       10     100pl            576.0
# 3       25     100pl             65.0
# 4       50     100pl            221.0
# 5      100     100pl            129.0

# use data.table - will be extremely fast.
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,list(IQR=IQR(Cy3_Fluorescence)),by=list(Molarity,Spot_Size)]
#    Molarity Spot_Size   IQR
# 1:      100     100pl 129.0
# 2:       50     100pl 221.0
# 3:       25     100pl  65.0
# 4:       10     100pl 576.0
# 5:        5     100pl 478.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had this problem today and it was easier to solve:

```
library(tidyverse)
#get IQR
a <- df %>% group_by(Spot_Size) %>% group_by(Molarity) %>% summarise(IQR(Cy3_Fluorescence))
a <- data.frame(a)
a
#  Molarity IQR.Cy3_Fluorescence.
#        5                 478.5
#       10                 576.0
#       25                  65.0
#       50                 221.0
#      100                 129.0
```